# Is it possible to manipulate certain areas to spawn structure specific mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm creating a skyblock world, and I'd like it if I could change the space from 1000 70 1000 to -1000 90 1000 into a nether-fortress like space where blazes and wither skeletons can spawn. I don't want to use spawners, as I want to simulate the spawning mechanics of regular survival but in a skyblock world.

Comment: Survival or with commands?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just no spawners I guess?

Comment: It does matter. With commands you just use `/summon`.

Comment: but that's not the point. I want it so that it spawns naturally without player interaction.

Comment: You do not need any manual player interaction if you use command blocks.

Comment: there's a problem though, it only works if the chunks the command block is in is loaded. It might be feasible though, what commands do you need to put in?

Comment: Please don't change questions to ask something entirely different.  Use the Ask Question button for that.

Comment: I basically just reworded the question to what I wanted to ask. Sorry for the confusion, but I realize that I worded it wrong and I'm asking something else.

Comment: You can just summon blazes. It has nothing to do with nether fortresses then. If you just need that, you can look it up yourself. If that's not what you mean, please specify what you actually mean. Also, spawn chunks are always loaded, as well as blazes. And when you want stuff to spawn in a specific location, that location should be loaded anyway.

Comment: @Frank Please read the comments here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/344990/can-i-change-minecraft-structure-bounding-boxes

Comment: Again, if you have something different to ask, click on Ask Question. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: I didn't have anything new to ask, I reworded the question to what I actually wanted to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, blazes only spawn in:

- Nether Fortresses
- Blaze Spawners

You can't spawn blazes naturally.

Comment: I ment to say how do you "make" a nether fortress that spawns blazes?

Comment: Well, I don't think so, unless you have a blaze spawner.

Comment: Oh well! I guess I have to use spawners then. Thanks though!

Comment: No problem! :DDD